Visual Studio 2022 MASM32 linking problem
Please, help me with linking and compilation of 2 simple files. I tried changing extension of MyProcedure.asm to inc, decorating and undecorating of the name MyProcedure (masm started requesting double decorating then), making MyProcedure public, tried /coff but I cannot find the solution. I just want to compile 2 files (masm32) in Visual Studio 2022. I did link libraries correctly. I cannot change the system's PATH so I can only use Visual Studio 2022 menus, not the console.
When I try to compile these files I receive an error that _MyProcedure does not exist. I am unable to compile and run the program. I would appreciate help how to successfully compile this program. Due to limitations I have to use Ms Visual Studio menus and command buttons, I cannot type commands on the console (I cannot edit PATH of my operating system).
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

EXTERN MyProcedure:PROC  ; Deklaracja zewnętrznej procedury

.data
    message BYTE "Hello from Main.asm!", 0

.code
main PROC
    mov edx, OFFSET message
    call WriteString
    call CrLf
    call MyProcedure         
    call ExitProcess
main ENDP

END main

and MyProcedure.asm
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc
PUBLIC MyProcedure          

.data
    message BYTE "Hello from MyProcedure.asm!", 0

.code
MyProcedure PROC
    mov edx, OFFSET message
    call WriteString
    call CrLf
    ret
MyProcedure ENDP

END


You've not explained the issue you're having. You talk a lot about what you tried, but you've not told us what problem it is you're trying to solve. Can you [edit] your question to provide that information, so that we can try to help?

Try changing EXTERN MyProcedure:PROC to MyProcedure PROTO

Michael Petch solved my problem. It required changing EXTERN MyProcedure: PROC Into MyProcedure PROTO.
